# Stretch Button ignoring margin

Tags: html, css

I created 3 buttons which stretch a little once you hover over them. I do **not** want them to move their position while one of the other buttons next to them is stretching out.

This code here works:

```css
.stretch-button {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: padding 0.5s, margin 0.5s;
}

.stretch-button:hover {
  padding: 8px 25px 8px 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button class="stretch-button">
        One
    </button>

<button class="stretch-button">
        Two
    </button>

<button class="stretch-button">
        Three
    </button>
```

HOWEVER, under .stretch-button:hover, as soon as you change the left and right padding from 25px to - for example - 24px (or basically ANYTHING under 25px), the code doesn't work anymore and the buttons move while one is being stretched.

Why is that so? I set the margin to 0 in the hover section and I am confused.

Hope someone can explain the reasoning to me!

Comment: It also stops working with padding OVER 25px like 26px;

Comment: Correct, I also noticed that. But could you explain why? I dont understand the reason unfortunately...

Comment: if you make the padding too small and the buttons do not move, then the buttons will overlap, html prevents this effect .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the `stretch-button` class you have `padding-left` plus `margin-left` adding up to `25px` in both states, with and without `hover`.

i.e. `15px + 10px` or `25px + 0px`

When `padding-left` and `margin-left` do not add up to the same amount with and without hover, then you will have the effect you are observing.

The same applies to `padding-right` and `margin-right`.

I have created some more `divs` with different settings (and colors) to demonstrate this effect. The green buttons are your original buttons. Please observe the blue buttons. Here the buttons end up exactly the same size and in the same position as the green buttons. However, the transition times are different. Because of this, it is clearly visible that the position and size of the buttons change. Because you used the same transition time for the two effects, no movement of the button text was visible with the green buttons.

However, a study of the orange and black buttons shows the effect when the paddings are more or less than `25px`, in this case `20px` and `30px`.

To answer your question why the other buttons move when one is being stretched, you should first notice what happens when you hover over the orange or black `one` button. In this situation, the `two`, `three`, and `4` buttons both move (orange to the left, black to the right). However, when you hover over the orange or black `two` button, only the `three` and `4` button moves (again, orange to the left, black to the right). And notice the button you hover over will increase in size (which is what you want and expect).

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.stretch-button {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: padding 0.5s, margin 0.5s;
}

.twenty {
  background-color: orange;
}

.thirty {
  background-color: black;
}

.stretch-button:hover {
  padding: 8px 25px 8px 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.twenty:hover {
  padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
}

.thirty:hover {
  padding: 8px 30px 8px 30px;
}

.no-stretch-button {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.diff-times {
  background-color: blue;
  transition: padding 0.5s, margin 2.5s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="stretch-button">
    One
  </button>
  <button class="stretch-button">
    Two
  </button>
  <button class="stretch-button">
    Three
  </button> Your original buttons
</div>
<div>
  <button class="stretch-button diff-times">
    One
  </button>
  <button class="stretch-button diff-times">
    Two
  </button>
  <button class="stretch-button diff-times">
    Three
  </button> transition times are different
</div>
<div>
  <button class="no-stretch-button">
    One
  </button>
  <button class="no-stretch-button">
    Two
  </button>
  <button class="no-stretch-button">
    Three
  </button> Nothing happens to show position of original buttons
</div>
<div>
  <button class="stretch-button twenty">
    One
  </button>
  <button class="stretch-button twenty">
    Two
  </button>
  <button class="stretch-button twenty">
    Three
  </button>
  <button class="stretch-button twenty">
    4
  </button> padding-left + margin-left = 20px, not 25px
</div>
<div>
  <button class="stretch-button thirty">
    One
  </button>
  <button class="stretch-button thirty">
    Two
  </button>
  <button class="stretch-button thirty">
    Three
  </button>
  <button class="stretch-button thirty">
    4
  </button> padding-left + margin-left = 30px, not 25px
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your accurate answer, Peter. I definitely got a better overview and appreciate the effort, however, I have to admit that I still haven't understood one thing: I now know that the paddings and margins need to be the same amount. But WHY do the other buttons move if margins and paddings aren't the same amount? Sorry once again, but I definitely want to make sure that I understood the root of the problem before I continue studying!

Comment: Thank you, I would love to see your updated answer as I feel the need to understand this properly.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's the [CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model#what_is_the_css_box_model) at work.

You've setup your styles to balance margin and padding. Looking at just these properties might make it easier to see what's happening:

```css
    .stretch-button {
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .stretch-button:hover {
        padding-left: 25px;
        padding-right: 25px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
```

Currently, the totals amount to `25px` on each side. So when you hover, the total space doesn't change and thus the button content remains stable.

If you, say, adjust the hover to `20px` *without* also making up the difference in the button, then the total are out-of-balance, and thus the button content shifts.

Here's a working example

```html
<style>
    .stretch-button {
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        transition: padding 0.5s,
            margin 0.5s;

    }

    .stretch-button:hover {
        padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
</style>

<button class="stretch-button">
    One
</button>

<button class="stretch-button">
    Two
</button>

<button class="stretch-button">
    Three
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now realized that I have to make up the difference in the button between padding and margin. But I still didn't  quite understand the reason: why does the content shift once the difference between padding and margin isn't made up?

Comment: Perhaps the key you're missing is understanding the [CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model#what_is_the_css_box_model)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way to do that is with other structure in the html code. I did another approach.

Now you just have to define the width of the button, the sum of all the widths must not be greater than that of the container. You also have to make sure that the width of the button container is not greater than the width of when hovered.

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: red;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  .button-region {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .button {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  
  .button:hover {
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='button-region'>
    <button class='button'> button 1</button>
  </div>
  <div class='button-region'>
    <button class='button'> button 1</button>
  </div>
  <div class='button-region'>
    <button class='button'> button 1</button>
  </div>
</div>
```